# how change date format in sql

Tags: sql

i created query!

```
SELECT install_time, Count(id) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT install_time, id 
FROM mytab
where event='run'
and install_time>='09.01.2017' and  install_time<='09.05.2017')
GROUP BY install_time
```

but `install_time` has that format like `09-05-2017 5:34:23`
but i need this format without hours,minutes and seconds

```
09-05-2017
```

How change this date format?

Comment: depends on the database being used. some databases have `date()` function to convert `datetime` to `date`.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  The answer to _this_ question is very relevant to _your_ question because date functions are very much database specific.  Oh, and please don't store dates as text in that format.

Comment: i use 12 version

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need a subquery.

Second, date/time functions vary by database.  Here is one method that assumes a `date()` function for removing the time component:

```
SELECT DATE(install_time), COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM mytab
WHERE event = 'run' AND
      install_time >= '2017-09-01' AND install_time < '2017-09-06'
GROUP BY DATE(install_time)
ORDER BY DATE(install_time);
```

Note that I also changed the date format to a standard format -- this works in most databases.  And, I changed the second comparison for `install_time` to take the time component into account.

Here are some equivalents to the `date()` function (which works in MySQL, SQLite, BigQuery, and DB2 at least):

- SQL Server:  `cast(install_time as date)`
- Postgres:    `date_trunc('day', install_time)`
- Oracle:      `trunc(install_time)`
- Teradata:    `cast(install_time as format 'YYYYMMDD')`

Comment: it worth to group conditions `event = 'run' AND (install_time >= '2017-09-01' and  install_time <='2017-09-05')`